# Can't Resolve "encoding" Module Error While Using Nextjs-13 + Supabase

Tags: typescript, npm, next.js, supabase

I'm trying to use Supabase for inserting/collecting data from my form. But when I compile I got encoding module is not found error. I already tried cache cleaning and re-installing npm modules. They didn't work either.

**Project Structure:**

[image]

**apply/page.tsx Code:**

```js
"use client"
import { supabase } from "lib/supabaseClient"

export default function Apply() {

    // This function called by button so we use "use client" at top.
    async function createApplyRecord() {
        const { error } = await supabase
            .from('applications')
            .insert({id: 1, fullname: "test", email: "aa", phone: "bb", githuburl: "cc", linkedinurl: "dd", about: "ee"})
            console.log("inserted")
            if(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
    }

  return (SOME HTML CODE HERE)
}
```

**Error I Got:**
[image]

Comment: Shot in the dark but maybe your node version is off? Might be worth updating it to the latest version.

Comment: Its up to date. I'm tried at LTS and Experimental versions. None of them changes anything.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is just a warning that can be safely ignored. We're working on removing it. You can follow along here: https://github.com/supabase/supabase-js/issues/612

Comment: Any case you know how to tell vercel to NOT treat this warning as error? My deploy is failing because of this. edit: found it https://vercel.com/guides/how-do-i-resolve-a-process-env-ci-true-error

Comment: @TasosTsournos remove the error for now using: npm i -D encoding

Comment: npm i -D encoding does the trick

Answer (score 14):

To fix this, I ran npm install encoding and the error was gone!

Answer (score 10):

I used a simple solution which was to use

> npm i -D encoding

But the supabase community should have already solved this problem. However, they changed the authentication mode with the new versions of next 13. Which is a serious problem because I didn't want to have to redo the authentication of my project.

Answer (score 2):

Update to the latest supabase version.

The issue is fixed

Via https://github.com/supabase/supabase-js/issues/612#issuecomment-1713493284

> Hey all, can you check if the errors are still there after upgrading supabase-js to v2.33.2?
> p.s. Please also try to uninstall encoding if you had to install that as a workaround. Thanks!