# Module not found: Can't resolve 'encoding' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/cross-fetch/node_modules/node-fetch/lib'

Tags: npm, next.js, supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

Has anyone come across this non-breaking warning issue that you get with the npm package: @supabase/supabase-js

```
The warning message:

warn  - ./node_modules/cross-fetch/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'encoding' in '/Users/maxsilva/Sites/kamapay/sasa-frontend/node_modules/cross-fetch/node_modules/node-fetch/lib'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/cross-fetch/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js
./node_modules/cross-fetch/dist/node-ponyfill.js
./node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/lib/fetch.js
./node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/SupabaseClient.js
./node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/main/index.js
./lib/supabaseClient.js
./app/[lng]/page.jsx
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't Resolve "encoding" Module Error While Using Nextjs-13 + Supabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75438048/cant-resolve-encoding-module-error-while-using-nextjs-13-supabase)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As stated in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75748298/module-not-found-cant-resolve-encoding-in-vercel-path0-node-modules-cross#comment133632652_75748298), you'll need to run this:

Vanilla NPM:

```
npm add -D encoding
```

PNPM:

```
pnpm add -D encoding
```

Comment: is it a bug, i am sure this error comes from some irregular code use . can you describe this error .

Comment: How exactly does this work ? I didn't need to install encoding before. Why all of a sudden ?